# Problem with maven in windows powershell. Error with /MAVEN/MojoFailureException

Tags: java, maven

I've been trying to get a project to work and I think I have an installation error with my maven download. I imported this java project by email and downloaded it. It's supposed to be full-proof without error the first time I activate it by its xml file, but I keep getting errors when trying to activate it. Here is the error every time I put in the command 'mvn package':

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyZNP.png)

Anyone know how to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: please paste the console output in your question directly and don't add images of text.

Comment: Please post your test code and your module-info.java file etc. otherwise it's impossible to help.